# How to close a floating window using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

One of my application processes occasionally creates a floating window that I'd like to programmatically auto-close.

I have no problem checking for the existence of this window through its name, but then I am unable to close it with neither `close window "windowname"` nor `tell window "windowname" to close`.

E.g.:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "processname"
    if exists window "windowname" then
        close window "windowname"
    end if
end tell
```

This result in:

> error "System Events got an error: window "windowname" of process "processname" doesn’t understand the “close” message."

How can I close this window, then?

Answer (score 2):

I can close a Finder window like this. Maybe you can do the same.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Finder"
        click button 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: No - none of the buttons of that window are the close button. It's a floating modal window.

Comment: How do you close it then? You haven't described any specifics about the window. Basically I'm suggesting to use UI Scripting to perform the task you physically perform. Do you click an OK button for example? If it's a default button then you can just "keystroke return". If it's not default then you can usually perform a number of tabs until the button is highlighted and then keystroke space. You need to give more information about how you physically close the window and then that can probably be automated.

Answer (score -1):

If "Command-W" closes the floating window, which it usually does, this will work:

```
tell application "System Events"
    if exists window "<window name>" of process "<application name>" then
        keystroke "w" using command down
    end if
end tell
```

You can also use Automator instead of AppleScript proper to do this. Record yourself clicking the close button.

When I do this, Automator records the action as, I kid you not, `Click the "<fill in title>" button.`